# stimulsoft report in visual studio don't display

Tags: stimulsoft

I create my report in  stimulsoft designer but the report in visual studio don't display, and encounter with following error: 
Error invoking 'Open Report from File'. Details:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
I use 29 panel in this report, when i remove one specific panel,report display in visual studio but other panel's destroy.

Comment: It's necessar to see your report template to help you.

Comment: What version of Stimulsoft assemblies do you use?

Comment: report  template is in http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1409111649

Comment: when remove panel 14 the report open in visual studio but content of other panel is destroy. Thanks

Comment: What code do you use to load report tempalte? There is no error on the currebnt build.

Comment: the report don't display in visual studio in design time while panel 14 is exist in report. the report i sent is without table else table of one panel go to table of another panel!

Comment: There is no content in any Panel. Can you show the initial report template?